# perf_counter()-start giving weird result

Tags: python, function, time, timeit

I was building my own version of the timeit function, which returns the amount of time it takes to run a function `n` times. However, when I ran it with a sample input, I received the following output, which doesn't seem right, as it ran very quickly.

```
9.400071576237679e-06
```

My code:

```
from time import perf_counter
from typing import Callable

class MyTimeit:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 
    def timeit(self, function: Callable, *parameters, num: int=10000):
        if not parameters:
            start = perf_counter()
            for _ in range(num):
                function()
            return perf_counter()-start
        else:
            start = perf_counter()
            for _ in range(num):
                function(*parameters)
            return perf_counter()-start

print(MyTimeit().timeit(lambda x: x<12, 10, n=100))
```

Why is it giving me this result? Is it a flaw in my programming logic, or am I missing something else?

Comment: That `e-06` suffix is telling you to move the decimal point over by six places.

Comment: The time value you got is in scientific notation. "e" stands for "10 to the power of", so you code ran in ~9.4 * 10^-9, or ~9.4 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, your function is just very fast, so it's executing in microseconds. You can test this using something that takes seconds to run, like `sleep`. Note that for very fast functions, the initial overhead is large compared to each run of the for loop. You can measure the overhead with `n = 0`.

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep
from typing import Callable

class MyTimeit:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 
    def timeit(self, f: Callable, *args, n: int=10000):
        if not args:
            s = perf_counter()
            for _ in range(n):
                f()
            return perf_counter()-s
        else:
            s = perf_counter()
            for _ in range(n):
                f(*args)
            return perf_counter()-s

print(MyTimeit().timeit(sleep, 1, n=5))
```